# Uncertain whether pirate talk be authentically or mockingly archaic

Tags: subjunctive-mood, archaicisms, be, pirate-english

@ZhanlongZheng asked the following [question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/23847/5289):

> > Barbosa: I defended her mightily enough, but she **be** sunk nonetheless.
> >
> > Jack Sparrow: If that ship **be** sunk properly, you should be sunk with it.
> >
> > — [*Pirates of the Caribbean: On Stranger Tides*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirates_of_the_Caribbean:_On_Stranger_Tides)
>
> I don't understand why **be** is used here twice. Is it archaic? Why use this form?

I think that the second instance of *be* could be present subjunctive in the third person, with the subjunctive being [appropriate due to it being in a conditional clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive).  I'm less sure about the first instance.

No doubt, use of the subjunctive has fallen out of favor, and nobody talks like that today.  However, I'd like to know, were these conjugations of *be* ever considered proper archaic English, or are they strictly pirate talk invented by Disney screenwriters?

Comment: I recall reading somewhere that the language of pirates was completely an invention of nineteenth-century writers.  With that being said, at least until Early Modern English, *be* was not always subjunctive: it was an independent verb that existed alongside *am, is, art, are.*  As a result, one could say either *I am* or *I be*, *he is* or *he beeth*, *thou art* or *thou beest*, and so on.  There was a subtle distinction between *am, is, art, are* and *be*, however, which the inventors of pirate-speak probably ignored.

Comment: There are some dialects that use "be" in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

Y'arr, it be as fake as a keg of rum-flavoured water:

- From the seahorse's mouth (Writers Guild of America): [Aye Before E, Except After Sea](http://www.wga.org/content/default.aspx?id=4875)
- National Geographic: ["Talk Like a Pirate Day" Busted: Not Even Pirates Spoke Pirate](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2011/09/110919-talk-like-a-pirate-day-2011-myths-busted-science-facts/)

Or just ask [skeptics.stackexchange.com](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/did-pirates-talk-the-way-they-are-currently-portrayed).

Comment: Fake pirate talk has already been [covered](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1216). I'd like to know, could these uses of _be_ also be considered grammatically correct in any current or archaic form of English?

Comment: Some English dialects, such as the West Country dialect on which 'pirate speak' is allegedly based, would have used 'it be' for 'it is'.