# Subjunctive "what be"

Tags: subjunctive-mood

> [1] "I don't know what is the best vehicle for that."
>
> [2] "I don't know what would be the best vehicle for that."
>
> [3] "I don't know what be the best vehicle for that."

My ear says [2] would be best. But [3] is shorter; is it also acceptable?

Comment: 3 is not correct English - it is Pirate speak

Comment: 2 is the best choice, but 1 is good too. 3 is not acceptable.

Comment: You'd use the subjunctive here in French, but I don't believe it ever was used here in English.

Comment: @mplungjan I like the "pirate" reference. I was going to ask why pirates talk like that, but found an existing question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171741/uncertain-whether-pirate-talk-be-authentically-or-mockingly-archaic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to express the idea contained in your example sentences without sounding unnatural:

> "I don't know what the best vehicle for that [thing] is."
>
> "I don't know what the best vehicle for that [thing] would be."
>
> "I don't know what would be the best vehicle for that [thing]."
>
> "I don't know the best vehicle for that [thing]."
>
> "I can't figure out the best vehicle for that [thing].

among others. Your option 1—

> "I don't know what is the best vehicle for that [thing]."

—sounds a little awkward to me, but there is nothing syntactically wrong with it. As mplungjan remarks above, "I don't know what be the best vehicle for that [thing]" has a Long John Silver ring to it and would not be a very suitable way to express the idea in modern idiomatic English.